# linq in lamda how to convert it to proper way

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin.forms

I have linq query with lamda expression(i think).

```
  public Register_person GetUsername(string mail1)
    {
  return Conn.Table<Register_person>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.UserName = mail1);
    }
```

I need this code to convert linq with from where and select but I could not to it.can anyone help me with this

Comment: The code you posted already uses linq. I can't work out what you're asking for.

Comment: @canton7 I think OP meant the linq query syntax, as opposed to dot notation.

Comment: yes it is on linq in as anomous method.i need this as like

Comment: var result =from table whre and then select

Comment: There´s no equivalent for `FirstOrDefault` in the query syntax.

Comment: this code just find but i need to edit this as before i mentioned

Comment: I would choose the above code over LINQ query any day, i mean what is wrong with lambda expressions?

Comment: It should probably be `t.UserName == mail1` not `t.UserName = mail1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `FirstOrDefault` in linq query syntax. The closest you can get is:

```
(from person in Conn.Table<Register_person>()
where person.UserName == mail1
select person).FirstOrDefault()
```

I think you'll agree that this adds a lot of noise for no gain.